# How to fix "too many open files" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am very frequently getting this error in MySQL:

> OS errno 24 - Too many open files

What's the cause and what are the solutions?

Comment: Check `SHOW PROCESSLIST` to see where these are coming from. Maybe a process has used up way too many inadvertently.

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Answer (score 11):

I was getting the `errno: 24 - Too many open files` too often when i was using many databases at the same time.

Solution

- ensure that the connections to db server close propertly
- edit /etc/systemd/system.conf. Uncomment and make

  ```
   DefaultLimitNOFILE=infinity
   DefaultLimitMEMLOCK=infinity
  ```

  then run `systemctl daemon-reload` and `service mysql restart`.

You can check the results with the query: `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'open_files_limit'` and you may notice that the value has changed. You should not have any errno 24 now.

Please notice that the solution may differ from other OS/versions. You can try to locate the variables first.Tested with Ubuntu 16.04.3 and mysql 5.7.19.

In my case it was useless to setting up the `open_files_limit` variable in mysql configuration files as the variable is flagged as a readonly.

I hope it helped!

Comment: Hi,  I had enough issues with mysql and memory leeks no to allow it LimitMEMLOCK=infinity.
Any clues on how to math ou that value?

Comment: Open connections have nothing to do with this error. A table can be closed as soon as it is no longer in use.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a `connection` leak in your application, that is why open `connections` are not closed once the `function` completes it's execution.

I would probably look into the application code and see where the `connections`/`preparedstatement` (if it's java) objects are not closed and fix it.

A quick workaround is to increase `ulimit` of the server (explained [here](https://duntuk.com/how-raise-ulimit-open-files-and-mysql-openfileslimit)) which would increase number of open file descriptors (i.e. `connections`). However, if you have a connection leak, you will encounter this error again, at later stages.

Comment: Thanks Darshan. I've verified several times for any connection leakage. There  is no leakage w.r.t. the connection.

Comment: Open connections have nothing to do with this error. A table can be closed as soon as it is no longer in use.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and found [a solution on another stackoverflow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56843659/oserror-errno-24-too-many-open-files-os-mojave).

By running the following snippet with Bash:

```sh
ulimit -n 30000
```